# How to detect new hard disk attached without rebooting?

Tags: linux, rhel, vmware, disk, scsi

I'm having a little issue. I've a live system which run on RHEL 6.7 (VM) and have VMware 6.5 (which is not managed by our group) . The issue is, the other group tried to extend the capacity of an existing disk on a VM. After that, I ran a scan command to detect new disk as usual with `echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/scan`, but nothing happened. They added 40G on sdb disk which should be 100G and I saw that is changed on VM but not in Linux. So where is the problem ? As I said, this is a live system, so I don't want to reboot it.

Here is the system :

```
# df -h /dev/mapper/itsmvg-bmclv
                       59G   47G  9.1G  84% /opt/bmc

# lsblk sdb                          8:16   0   60G  0 disk  └─itsmvg-bmclv (dm-2)      253:2    0   60G  0 lvm  /opt/bmc

# vgs   VG       #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree    itsmvg     1   1   0 wz--n- 59.94g     0 

# pwd   /sys/class/scsi_host

# ll lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Nov 13 16:18 host0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/host0/scsi_host/host0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Nov 13 16:19 host1 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/host1/scsi_host/host1 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Nov 13 16:19 host2 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/0000:03:00.0/host2/scsi_host/host2
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Below is the command that you need to run to scan the host devices so it will show the new hard disk connected.

```
echo "- - -" >> /sys/class/scsi_host/host_$i/scan
```

$i is the host number

Comment: As I said in the question, I already run  echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/scan  (and host1 & host2) . But nothing happend. What's wrong ?

Comment: Use below command
echo 1 >>/sys/class/scsi_device/device/rescan

Comment: For scanning exsisting hd need to use above command which i mentioned

Comment: The problem is solved. I don't know why but when they extend the existing disk on VM, linux didn't detect it with command i mentioned. But I just wanna try add new disk , not expand existing disk; it is fixed. So should I run   echo “- - -“ >> /sys/class/scsi_host/host_$i/scan  after expand disk ? and what is echo 1 >>/sys/class/scsi_device/device/rescan command do ?

Comment: What is the significance of "- - -"? Why this particular string?

Comment: The three dashes act as wildcards to rescan everything: channel, SCSI target ID, and LUN.

Comment: Didn't work for me. (kernel 5.4.0-173-generic on Ubuntu). What worked was `echo - - - | sudo tee /sys/class/scsi_device/*/device/rescan`.

Answer (score 28):

As was mentioned above, you could scan all existing hosts with a one-liner:

```
for host in /sys/class/scsi_host/*; do echo "- - -" | sudo tee $host/scan; ls /dev/sd* ; done
```

and the result:

```
$ for host in /sys/class/scsi_host/*; do echo "- - -" | sudo tee $host/scan; ls /dev/sd* ; done
- - -
/dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sda2  /dev/sdb  /dev/sdb1  /dev/sdc  /dev/sdc1
- - -
/dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sda2  /dev/sdb  /dev/sdb1  /dev/sdc  /dev/sdc1

    ︙

- - -
/dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sda2  /dev/sdb  /dev/sdb1  /dev/sdc  /dev/sdc1
- - -
/dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sda2  /dev/sdb  /dev/sdb1  /dev/sdc  /dev/sdc1
- - -
/dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sda2  /dev/sdb  /dev/sdb1  /dev/sdc  /dev/sdc1  /dev/sdd  /dev/sdd1
```

The last line shows us `/dev/sdd` device was discovered.

Comment: you may use `lsblk -S` instead of `ls /dev/sd*`

Comment: of 16 disks this helped me raise the discovered disk count from 13 to 15 ^^

Answer (score 21):

This worked for me to refresh all devices:
(As an easier to run command)

```
echo "- - -" | tee /sys/class/scsi_host/host*/scan
```

The three dashes act as wildcards to rescan everything: channel, SCSI target ID, and LUN.

Comment: This one worked like a charm! I had added a disk via VMWare and linux instance did not see it until running this command.

Comment: @jak0lantash Best solution IMO. On Debian/Ubuntu, use `sudo tee` instead of `tee`.

Comment: Didn't work for me. (kernel 5.4.0-173-generic on Ubuntu). What worked was `echo - - - | sudo tee /sys/class/scsi_device/*/device/rescan`.

Answer (score 2):

How about this :

To scan for new disks :

```shell
echo "- - -" | sudo tee /sys/class/scsi_host/host*/scan >/dev/null
```

To rescan existing disks :

```shell
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/block/sd?/device/rescan >/dev/null
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try to run

```
partprobe
```

This command checks for changes in the partition table and notifies the OS about it.

Comment: We use this too, working.